# How to Skip Over Word in Loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I have the following strings:

```
str=["If we go to the park, we will find a big slide!"];

replacer=[["to","a"],["a","un"]];
```

I then iterate through str and replace each occurrence of "to" with "a" and then each occurrence of "a" with "un" and end up with:

```
str=["If we go un the park, we will find un big slide!"];
```

I understand that in this simple case I could reverse the replacer values but that is not an option for me.  Is there anyway I could put some kind of disclaimer or flag with the replaced word so that when I iterate through for the next variable it skips the already replaced word?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand the question very well. So you want to replace all occurrences of "to" - "a" and then "a" - "un". However those strings which were converted from "to"-"a" should not be touched during the second replace is it?
Is the expected output "If we go a the park, we will find un big slide!"?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am going for!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var str=["If we go to the park, we will find a big slide!"];
function replacer(str, oldarr, newArr)
{
  oldarr.forEach( function(value,index){

     str = str.replace( new RegExp(value, "g"), newArr[index] );

  } );
  return str;
}
replacer(str[0],["to","a"],["a","un"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split `str` by space to array, and then iterate over each word, saving "used" index to temporary array not to overwrite it again, then join this array back to string:

```
var str = ["If we go to the park, we will find a big slide!"];
var replacer = [["to","a"],["a","un"]];
var ar = str[0].split(' ');
var used = [];//temporary array to hold indexes of changes values
replacer.forEach(function(v,k){
    ar.forEach(function(x,i){
        if(used.indexOf(i) < 0){
            if(x == v[0]){
                ar[i] = v[1];
                used.push(i);
            }
        }
    });

});
str = [ar.join(' ')];
console.log(str);
```

Output:

```
["If we go a the park, we will find un big slide!"]
```